# how to access to a property file in other folder from unit test

Tags: java, maven, junit

I'm facing an error when launching my test, the problem is properties file.

this property file is in my application resource folder and I'm in "folder2" test folder.

```
--application
  --src
    --main
      --resources
        --application.properties
--folder2
  --main
    --test
      --path.to.package
        --ClassWithTest.java
```

how can access to this application.propeties file?

I have this in my ClassWithTest:

```
@TestPropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
```

that only works if I copy the file into my Resources under folder2,but this is not what I need to do.

I'm using Java and it is a maven project

Comment: from my experience, copying application.properties to /test/resources folder is a common practice. Nothing wrong with it.

Comment: I assume "application" and "folder2" are Maven modules or even standalone projects. If so, make sure that the module/project under "folder2" *depends on* the module/project under "application". Posting the relevant parts of your Maven configuration might help getting a more specific answer. The folder structure above, if not a typo, is strange for Maven, i.e. no `src` folder and `test` under `main`.

Comment: Property files should be located in `src/main/resources/<OptionalPackage>` for production code and for test code in `src/test/resources/<OptionalPackage>` ...there should be no folder `folder2` there...

Comment: @gneginskiy That's simply wrong. It shows that the basic concepts of Maven have not been understood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic setup for any kind of project in Maven is first to follow the default directory layout which looks like the following:

```
.
|-- pom.xml
`-- src
    |-- main
    |   |-- java
    |   `-- resources
    `-- test
        |-- java
        `-- resources
```

In the `src/main/java/<packageName>` you put your production classes (`*.java`) and the property files have to go into `src/main/resources` (for example `application.properties`.

The unit- tests and or integration test classes will belong into `src/test/java/<packageName>/` . Unit test should be named like `*Test.java` while integration tests should be named like `*IT.java`..
If you have particular property files for testing only they belong into `src/test/resources` directory.

To have particular configurations for your tests can simply achieved by using the multi-document yaml file in your test resources (`src/test/resources/application.yaml`):

```
---
spring:
  profiles:
    active: xtest
....
```

The parts after profile can be used to do particular configuration for your test setup...which can be activated via `@ActiveProfiles("xtest")`  within your tests...
Or you can also name a different file `test-application.properties` and use `@TestPropertySource("classpath:test-application.properties")` in your test instead (`src/test/resources/test-application.properties`).

It's technically doable to filter resource files which can be achieved via using filtering. Most of the time related to spring boot resources (application.properties/application.yaml) is make no sense (rare case excluded).

Resource filtering:

- https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html#How_do_I_filter_resource_files
- https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html

Comment: can you point to the official documentation, where the defaults setup for resource filtering and how to configure those, if one isn't happy with the defaults, is decribed. That would be really helpful, thanks